# Changing javascript snippet background and text colors

Tags: javascript

Can I change the color of this snippet I got from 100 widget? I would like (love) the image color to be 2a5500 (green) and the text to be white.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand, what do you mean exactly, but Anyway you can use `elem.style.background` and `elem.style.color` .

**Example:**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="elem" style="width:400px; height:250px; border:1px solid"> Welcome </div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var elem = document.getElementById('elem');
elem.onmouseover = function(){
  elem.style.background = "#2a5500";
  elem.style.color = "#ff0080";
}
elem.onmouseout = function(){
  elem.style.background = "";
  elem.style.color = "";
}
```